# ko.mapping.fromJS not mapping nested value after value is set null

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am applying JSON data to my ViewModel using `ko.mapping.fromJS`. This JSON data has nested objects within it, like so:

```
var data = {
   item : "#1234",
   description: "This is item #1",
   moreinfo: {
       condition: "Good"
   }
}
```

When I try to re-map new data to the object it works fine, updating all the values. However, if I remap the value of `moreinfo` to `null`because this item doesn't have moreInfo, like so:

```
var data2 = {
   item : "#4567",
   description: "This is item #2",
   moreinfo:null
}
```

it doesn't update the DOM but instead keeps the previous value `condition:"Good"`. If I then update the value one more time to data that has `moreinfo`, like so:

```
var data3 = {
   item : "#7890",
   description: "This is item #3",
   moreinfo: {
       condition: "Bad"
   }
}
```

it still updates the item and description, but still it doesn't update the DOM but instead keeps the value `condition:"Good"`.

Am I using mapping incorrectly or can you just not allow the value to become `null`?

**Javascript:**

```
var viewModel;
$("#button1").on("click", function(){
   viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("itemWrapper")[0]);
});
$("#button2").on("click", function(){
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data2, {}, viewModel);
});
$("#button3").on("click", function(){
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data3, {}, viewModel);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="itemWrapper">
    <p data-bind="text: item"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: description"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: moreinfo.condition"></p>
</div>

<button id="button1">
Bind Data #1
</button>
<button id="button2">
Bind Data #2
</button>
<button id="button3">
Bind Data #3
</button>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hrgx5f1y/

- If you applyBindings with Button #1, then map the null with #2, then map new values with #3 you will see the issue I describe.
- If you applyBindings with Button #1, then map new values with #3, then map new values with #4 (none of these are null) it works perfectly.

Comment: General tip: You don't want to let jQuery do any top-level event handling in a knockout application. The only place where jQuery that touches the DOM in any way is appropriate (i.e. attaching to events, modifying CSS classes, creating HTML) is in a custom binding handler. All primary event handling and DOM manipulation is supposed to be done through knockout bindings.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the advice, this was just a quick mock up so that people would have an example to go off of. The real application only maps the data after an ajax call, although I suppose that is still a jQuery event.

Comment: That's why I said "that touches the DOM in any way". Using jQuery as your Ajax library is fine. The point is that you don't want jQuery to modify the DOM without Knockout being in control of it. (Just for the sake of it, here's a variant that works without the mapping plugin:  https://jsfiddle.net/hrgx5f1y/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that Knockout binding handlers work is that they hook up to an observable, and they respond when that observable changes. It does not bind to *your binding expression* but to your *observable object* So your binding:

```
<p data-bind="text: moreinfo.condition"></p>
```

...takes the `condition` property of `moreinfo`, which is an observable object and subscribes to it. When you do this:

```
 var data4 = {
   item : "#0000",
   description: "This is item #4",
   moreinfo: {
       condition: "Meh"
   }
 }
 ko.mapping.fromJS(data4, {}, viewModel);
```

...it works because Knockout can tie the structure of `data4` to your view model and update that exact same observable object with the new value `'Meh'`.

If you do this instead:

```
var data2 = {
  item : "#4567",
  description: "This is item #2",
  moreinfo:null
}
$("#button2").on("click", function(){
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data2, {}, viewModel);
});
```

...it is not updating that observable, but rather is updating the `moreinfo` property so it's null. Since a binding is to an observable object, not an *expression*, even if you update the view model so `moreinfo` isn't null anymore, the binding expression is not re-evaluated; your DOM is still bound to that same original observable.

You can work around this by having `moreinfo` as an observable, binding to it, and subsequently binding to `condition`; that way, if either updates, your DOM will update as expected. For example:

```
<!-- ko with:moreinfo -->
  <p data-bind="text: condition"></p> 
<!-- /ko -->
```